# Site não abre com https no telemóvel?

Tags: cpanel, google

Algo que me ocorreu recentemente foi pesquisar o website que estou a fazer no `Google`, no entanto, quando entro no link apresentado na pesquisa, ele não redireciona para o site com `https` enquanto no pc ele redireciona direito. Existe alguma forma de mudar isso? Tentei usar a ferramenta de Redirecionar do Cpanel mas por alguma razão entrava num loop infinito e dava erro `403 - Forbidden`.

Eis o link da pesquisa: [Link da Pesquisa](https://www.google.pt/search?q=famalicao%20digital&oq=famalicao%20digital&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l2j0l3.6023j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)